# How to access different portions of a json data-structure?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

```
{
"commands" : [
           {"command" : [
                         {"name" : "Base ls Command","shell" : "ls"},
                         {"name" : "Advanced ls command" : "shell" : "ls -la"}
              ]
           },
          {"command":[
                             {"name" :"Base netstat command", "shell" : "netstat"},
                             {"name" : "Advanced netstat command" : "shell" : "netstat -tunalp | grep LISTEN | grep nginx"}
             ]
          }
 ]
}
```

So, that I can access it as follows:

```
for cmd in file[commands][command]:
    'name' = cmd['name']
    shell = cmd['shell']
```

But, I am getting invalid syntax error.

Comment: Why do you have the name as a string, it should be a variable

Answer (score 1):

You should use the json module to load the file correctly.

```
import json

command = json.load(open('file_name.json'))

name = command['commands']['command']['name']
```

you can read more about the module in the documents: https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html